# Calculating Price Elasticity of Demand

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

Hi I was given the following price vs quantity values.

```
Price   Quantity Demanded
4   221
5   210
6   185
7   162
8   144
9   122
10  102
11  81
12  61
13  46
14  25
```

The graph was plotted as shown below.

[image]

The equation was, $Y = -0.0496 X + 15.133$. What I need to know is, I was asked to find the PED when price is $\$7.5$.

Then what I did was, I found the quantity at price $7.5$ substituting to the price quantity equation. And then found the PED using the equation

[image]

The quantity derived for price $7.5$ was $153.89$. Then I calculated the PED as below. Is it correct?

$$\frac{(153.89-144)/144}{(7.5-8)/8} = 1.099$$

May I know whether this calculation is correct?

Comment: Is Y = -0.0496 X + 15.133 your formula for quantity demanded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer will vary slightly depending on which notion of elasticity you're using.

[**Arc elasticity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_elasticity) (or **midpoint** elasticity) uses the formula
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^\text{arc}=\frac{Q_1-Q_0}{P_1-P_0}\cdot\frac{\frac12(Q_0+Q_1)}{\frac12(P_0+P_1)},
\end{equation}
where $\frac12(Q_0+Q_1)$ is the midpoint between $Q_0$ and $Q_1$. Note that in your case, $7.5$ is the midpoint between $7$ and $8$.

[**Point elasticity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function) uses the formula
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^\text{point}=\frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dP}\cdot\frac{P}{Q}.
\end{equation}
Here, $\frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dP}$ is the derivative of the demand function (evaluated at the point you want to calculate the elasticity, but it will be constant if demand is linear), and in your case, $P=7.5$ and $Q$ is the quantity demanded corresponding to that price.

Comment: Thanks alot Herr. :) Corrected it . I'm having another small question. The PED value I received at price 7.5 is, 0.9641. Does it mean this is inelastic since it is smaller than 1. What Can I do to increase the revenue of the product. Increase or decrease the product

Comment: @Hiru: If you assume linear demand, then there is a nice property you can use. Suppose $Q^*$ is the quantity where $\epsilon=1$, then we must have $\epsilon >1$ for all $Q<Q^*$ and $\epsilon <1$ for all $Q>Q^*$.